# Strongly-typed navigation between components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I want to ensure that URLs to navigate between components are valid and strongly-typed, meaning: having matching params and query string params. Thus, when a component changes the URLs it accepts, it should break any invalid usages. I have a potential solution which is written below. **Are there better ways to solve my problem, other than what is written below? I'm using react-router 3, but solutions with 4 or other packages are also welcome.** The solution must support component *x* linking to component *y* and *y* linking back to *x*.

This is a potential solution:

**getSomeComponentUrl.ts**

```
export interface ISomeComponentQuery {
    someArgument?: string;
    origin?: 'x' | 'y' | 'z';
}

export interface ISomeComponentParams {
    id?: string;
}

export const getSomeComponentUrl = (input: ISomeComponentQuery & ISomeComponentParams ) => 
    getUrlWithId('someComponentRootUrl', input);
```

**getUrlWithId.ts**

```
import { stringify } from 'query-string';

export function getUrlWithId(root: string, input: { id?: string }): string {
    const { id, ...queryStringParams } = input;
    if (!id) {
        throw Error(`"/${root}/" requires an id.`);
    }
    return `/${root}/${input.id}?${stringify(queryStringParams)}`;
}
```

**someOtherComponent.ts**

```
import { getSomeComponentUrl } from '../someComponent/getSomeComponentUrl';

getSomeComponentUrl({ id: item.id, origin: 'x', someArgument: this.someArgument });
```

A downside to this approach is having to create `getSomeComponentUrl` functions for each component that can be navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `getSomeComponentUrl` in base `class`, make this function generic typed and by default all component that will extend your base class will be 'navigable' back and forth. This base class can as well implement private `id` string, to ensure it's presence while component creation

But providing interface with typing is the best solution for your need.